# C: deleting elements mid array and have previous pointers working

Tags: c, arrays

I have several arrays like this (please ignore specific names):

```
static resource_t coap_cmp_res[MAX_CMPS];
e.g. [cmp1,cmp2,cmp3,cmp4,cmp5,0,0,0]
```

and a code that uses these elements, for example, coap_cmp_res[4] (cmp5) is associated with a REST resource, call it Res5.

At a certain point in time, I delete an element in that array at position x like this:

```
    rest_deactivate_resource(&coap_cmp_res[x]);
    e.g. for x = 2
    [cmp1,cmp2,0,cmp4,cmp5,0,0,0]
```

What I then would like to do is have a single continuous array again like this

```
e.g. [cmp1,cmp2,cmp4,cmp5,0,0,0,0]
```

What I do currently is:

```
for(UInt8 i = x; i < MAX_CMPS; i++){
    coap_cmp_res[i] = coap_cmp_res[i+1];
}
which gives [cmp1,cmp2,cmp4,cmp5,cmp5,0,0,0]
```

then I manually set the last non-zero element to 0.

```
e.g. [cmp1,cmp2,cmp4,cmp5,0,0,0,0]
```

So, this looks good, but the problem is that the Res5 is still associated with  coap_cmp_res[4] and thus now the value 0, instead of cmp5, which is not what I desire.

I could deactivate and reactivate every resource after x in the array to have the associations working again, but was wondering if there was a more efficient way to go about this.
Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: I don't really know a more efficient way in array, but if you can change the data representation, maybe linked list can do this better.

Comment: You can't just put the last element of the array in the free spot you just created and update all reference to the last element ?
That's very quick if you got only one reference to each element...

Comment: Instead of an array of values, use an array of pointers. Then you can have other variables with the same pointers, instead of pointing to the array elements.

Comment: I rolled back your post to your original question. You can still see the edit history of the post in the link above the last edit stamp.

Answer (score 0):

As the proverb says: "add a level of indirection". An array of `resource_t*` that point into `coap_cmp_res` and are stable. Then have `Rea5` associated with a pointer, and use the indirection to reach into a valid entry.

```
static resource_t  coap_cmp_res_data[MAX_CMPS];
static resource_t* coap_cmp_res_ptrs[MAX_CMPS]; // points into coap_cmp_res_data
```

When you remove an element, you update the entries in `coap_cmp_res_ptrs`, without moving them, and shrink `coap_cmp_res_data`. Any resource will still refer to the same position in `coap_cmp_res_ptrs`, and the indirection will take it to the current location of the resource.

An alternative approach, which may prove better in your case (you'd have to profile), is to use node based storage. I.e a linked list.

Comment: @Sven - If you have a question about the solution, post another question. Don't edit this one. This is the guideline for keeping SO tidy, posts useful and increasing your chances of getting help.

Comment: @Sven - You can add a link to this post from your new one for reference,